# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^n}{(2n)!}$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I'm trying to evaluate this limit. $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^n}{(2n)!}$$ I know that $n^n$ grows faster than $n!$. So the result should be $+\infty$. But the real result is zero. Why?

Comment: Try using Stirling's approximation and substituting in

Answer (score 9):

Note that $$0 \le \dfrac{n^n}{(2n)!} = \dfrac{1}{n!}\cdot\dfrac{n \cdot n \cdots n}{(n + 1)\cdot(n+2)\cdots(2n)} \le \dfrac{1}{n!} \to 0.$$

Answer (score 7):

$n^n$ grows faster than $n!$ but slower than $(2n)!$, since:

$$(2n)! = (2n)(2n-1)\dots(n+1)n! > n^nn!$$

Hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {n^n}{(2n)!} \le \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {n^n}{n^nn!} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {1}{n!} = 0$$

The confusion may be from the fact that $(2n)! \ne 2n!$.

Answer (score 2):

$(2n)!\approx\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}e\right)^{2n}=2\sqrt{\pi}\left(\frac2e\right)^{2n}n^{2n+1/2}$
so:
$$\frac{n^n}{(2n)!}=\frac{n^n}{2\sqrt{\pi}\left(\frac2e\right)^{2n}n^{2n+1/2}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\left(\frac e2\right)^{2n}n^{\frac12-n}$$
now as we take the limit notice that the $e/2$ term grows slower than the $n$ term when both raised to a power of $n$ and so it goes towards $0$

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}}{\frac{n^n}{(2n)!}}=\dfrac{(2n)!\cdot (n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n\cdot (2n+2)!}=\dfrac{n+1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^n\to0<1$